# Como chamar determinada categoria para uma página wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Estou criando um tema para wordpress mas não estou conseguindo chamar determinada categoria em uma página ( que está no menu ) .

Por exemplo : Tenho uma página no menu sobre MUSICAS e gostaria que chamasse 1 categoria exemplo : ROCK.

Tentei com o código abaixo mas apareceu todas as categorias não somente a que citei acima ( https://wordpress.org/support/topic/display-the-posts-of-one-category-in-a-page-solved )

```
     <?php
      /* Template name: solo */
     ?>

    <?php get_header(); ?>

    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
         <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

    <?Php 
    query_posts ('cat = 15 '); 

    while (have_posts ()): the_post (); 
    the_content (); 
    endwhile; 
    ?>

         </main>
    </div>

   <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo que observei você está usando uma Página como template logo a $wp_query global(padrão) do arquivo trará na verdade a query do Modelo da Página e não a query de uma categoria mesmo que você altere no método query_posts(),para que tal coisa acontecesse você teria que usar um taxonomy.php ou category.php . 
Para resolver seu problema você precisa criar uma nova WP_Query;

```
$customQuery = new WP_Query('cat=15');
if($customQuery->have_posts()) :
   while($customQuery->have_posts()): $customQuery->the_post();
       the_content();
   endwhile;
endif;
```

Para mais informações e exemplos: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters